# Paint textview opacity and size from seekbar Android

Tags: android, canvas, seekbar, watermark

I'm developing a simple watermark apps where user will upload an image and is able to edit the opacity and text size of the watermark textview by using Seekbar. After finished edit, user will press the save button to save the edited textview. The final result should be a new image with included watermark textview edited by user. I'm using Canvas method to draw watermark textview on the uploaded image. However I'm facing problem with the data set at seekbar is not pass through the canvas and my final result is new image created with no watermark textview. Please give me guidance. Thanks. 
Here's the seekbars code for user to edit text size and opacity:-

```
        SeekBar trans=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.main_sb_transparent);
        SeekBar size=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.main_sb_size);
        TextView water_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.watertext);
        float Alpha; // store the text opacity value
        int Size; // store the text size value

        trans.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                          Alpha=(float)(trans.getProgress())/(float)(seekBar.getMax());
                          water_text.setAlpha(Alpha);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

            });

       size.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {

                    Size=size.getProgress();
                    water_text.setTextSize(Size);
                }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

        });

    }
```

Here's the function to draw watermark text to the uploaded image:-

```
private Bitmap drawText(Bitmap source)
{
    int width=source.getWidth();
    int height=source.getHeight();
    Bitmap result=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas=new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source,0,0,null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(colors);
    paint.setTypeface(font);
    paint.setAlpha((int) (Alpha)); // <== Alpha value obtained from seekbar
    paint.setTextSize(Size);    <== Size value obtained from seekbar
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    int xPos=(canvas.getWidth()/2);
    int yPos=(int)((canvas.getHeight()/2)-((paint.descent()+paint.ascent())/2));

    canvas.drawText(edited, xPos, yPos, paint);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What if u name Alpha as myAlpha and mySize.  Not sure but Alpha could be a system thing

Comment: Have tried change the name Alpha and Size to myAlpha and mySize, but the end result still don't have the watermark edited from Seekbar.

Comment: Put a`Log` statement right after u update the value of Alpha in your `onProgressChangedListener` which logs the value of Alpha. And post your results. After that we can see where the error is. Also log the value for you size value and also in your bitmap Draw text.  Then post your results :)

Comment: Here's the result that I obtained through Log. 

04-25 21:51:58.005: D/Test(31172): myAlpha value: 0.49,     
04-25 21:51:59.065: D/Test(31172): mySize value: 40,     
04-25 21:52:18.670: D/Test(31172): myAlpha value in drawText: 0.49 ,    
04-25 21:52:18.670: D/Test(31172): mySize value in drawText: 40,

Comment: Here's the log that I inserted:- 
`myAlpha=(float)(trans.getProgress())/(float)(seekBar.getMax());
     water_text.setAlpha(myAlpha);
     Log.d("Test", "myAlpha value: " + myAlpha);`

Comment: Another log inserted on paint part in drawText

`Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(colors);
  paint.setTypeface(font);
  paint.setAlpha((int)myAlpha);
  Log.d("Test", "myAlpha value in drawText: " + myAlpha);
  paint.setTextSize((float)mySize);
  Log.d("Test", "mySize value in drawText: " + mySize);
  paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);`

Comment: Well all your Alpha and size values are updated. There must be an error in the paint you are calling. Also try changing `paint.setAlpha((int) (Alpha))` to `paint.setAlpha(Integer.parseInt(myAlpha))` and also consider checking online of that is the write way to use paint. Because your values are updated. Sorry I don't know much about `Paint`. Will try to search about it though